# Entity Framework and SQL Server adds blanks in strings?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am building a ASP.NET MVC application with Entity Framework and SQL Server.

I have noticed that when I read back SQL Server columns of type `nchar` or `text` there will be added blanks at the end of the string. To fix this I have to run Trim() on the string?

How can I solve this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I have notice that when I read back MS
>   SQL columns of type nchar

`NCHAR` is *fixed length*.  If an `INSERT`ed or `UPDATE`ed value has a smaller length, then spaces are added. Naturally you read back with additional blanks.

This happens when the database is set up in such a way to add blanks.

if you do not want fixed length strings, *don't use a fixed length field type*. Instead of `NCHAR` use `NVARCHAR`. The `VAR` in there indicates variable length.

Comment: I spent hours trying to figure out the reason for this. Is there a reason why you'd ever want to fill in the rest of the characters with blanks?

Answer (score 1):

TomTom's answer is correct but if you were like me you may still be having an issue.

I changed my table column to `varchar(10)` but was still having the spacing issue. I found that my issue was also with my Entity Context definition. Make sure in your `.modelBuilder.Entity<your_table>()` does not have the property `.IsFixedLength()` on it. I took that out and that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have two extension methods that will trim nchar fields within entities. The first will trim a single entity, and the second uses the first to trim a list of entities.

```
public static T TrimSingleEntity<T>(this T entity)
    {
        if (entity == null) return entity;
        var props = entity.GetType()
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                .Where(prop => prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead);
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var value = (string)prop.GetValue(entity, null);
            if (value == null) continue;
            value = value.Trim();
            prop.SetValue(entity, value, null);
        }
        return entity;
    }

public static List<T> TrimEntityList<T>(this List<T> entityList)
    {
        foreach (var entity in entityList) TrimSingleEntity(entity);
        return entityList;
    }
```